# Alexa Skill Certification - Validating amazon request

Tags: nginx

I have submitted a skill for certification to Alexa and they replied with issue saying that my server is ignoring invalid SSL certificates.  Amazon has a strict requirement to make sure that the server properly verify the incoming request SSL certificate.

My setup is Nginx + Nodejs + Alexa-skills-app where I use letsencrypt to have a proper SSL certificates for nginx. My server is able to send and receive all response without any issues, but for the skill to be certified, nginx has to make sure that incoming requests from amazon are properly verified.

Does anyone know which nginx configuration I should use to force proper SSL verification on incoming requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out later on that Alexa sends those verification strings and URL in the http headers that needs to be verified. There is a npm module alexa-verify that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Https SSL certificate files(*.pem) need to attach on both Nodejs and Nginx server
Then only all the request will come from https://
which they will be consider safe.